# Postgres SQL to get the data after a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in table 1 that shows the service code for customers along with their service date. The table #2 shows the service code and the order number associated with that service code and when that order took place i.e., report_date.  As shown in the desired_result, I want to see the count of distinct orders for each service code that took place after the service_date.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the query that returns `srvc_cust_code` and distinct count of orders per `srvc_cust_code` where the `report_date` is later than `service_date`:

```
SELECT srvc_cust_code, count(DISTINCT orders) FROM table1
    JOIN table2 USING (srvc_cust_code)
    WHERE report_date > service_date
    GROUP BY srvc_cust_code;
```

If you need more info, please take a look at [the PostgreSQL Documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/index.html)
[7.2. Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html) (infomation on `JOIN`, `USING` and `GROUP BY`)
[4.2.7. Aggregate Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) (information on function `count()` and `DISTINCT`)

Comment: Please add explanation

Comment: A bit of explanation + links the documentation added.